# Sending email using nodemailer got stuck on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, nodemailer

So we use package nodemailer for sending emails using Node.js API. It works fine localy on Windows, using `smtp.gmail.com`. Once we move node API to **Ubuntu 16.04**, sending emails **stop working**. The rest of the API works fine.
On our gmail account, we enabled both:

1. https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and
2. https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Code:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ 
    //tried other combinations aswell
    service: 'gmail', 
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    //tried port 465 and secure:true
    port: 587, 
    secure: false, 
    auth: { 
        user: 'sender@gmail.com', 
        pass: 'password' 
    } 
});


var mailOptions = {
    from: 'sender@gmail.com',
    to: 'reciever@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Welcome',
    html: "Hello": 
};`
```

We tried other mail providers, such as outlook, zoho, yandex,...The timeout happens everytime. Firewall on Ubuntu is disabled, also the installation is fresh.

**SOLUTION**

The problem was on service provider, where Ubuntu was hosted.

Comment: Sounds like a network issue

Comment: That's not a programming question. If you don't know how to check network connectivity, port settings, etc. then your going to need to do some reading on linux shell commands. [Here's a start](https://serverfault.com/questions/309052/check-if-port-is-open-or-closed-on-a-linux-server)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggesting to bypass the network problem via Google's API.

You need to generate an OAUTH CLIENT ID via the API manager at Google Console, then choose "Web Application"; Once you have your Authorization code you can use the following code:

```
<pre>
  var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
  sails.log.debug("try to send mail");
  var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
      service: "Gmail",
      auth: {
        XOAuth2: {
          user: "xxx@gmail.com", // Your gmail address.
          clientId: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
          clientSecret: "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
          refreshToken: "REFRESH_TOKEN_YOU_JUST_FOUND"
        }
      }
    });

  var mailOptions = {
      from: "xxx@gmail.com", // sender address
      to: RECEIVER_EMAIL", // list of receivers
      subject: "A_SUBJECT", // Subject line
      // text: ", // plaintext body
      html: htmlBody // html body
    };
  // send mail
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
      if (error) {
        sails.log.debug(error);
        return res.notOk({
          status: "error",
          msg: "Email sending failed"
        })
      } else {
        console.log("Message %s sent: %s", info.messageId, info.response);
        return res.ok({
          status: "ok",
          msg: "Email sent"
        })
      }
      smtpTransport.close();
    });
</pre>
```